# How to find sum of first three salary where total rows on the table six rows

Tags: sql

How to find  sum of first three salary where total rows on the table six rows.

```
id      Salary
01       100
02       200
03       300
04       400
05       500
06       600
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this.....

```
SELECT SUM(salary) 
FROM
    (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER, salary
     FROM tablename) AS foo
WHERE 
    ROW_NUMBER <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
SELECT SUM(Salary)
FROM (
    SELECT Salary FROM your_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 3
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it to be SQL Server:

```
 SELECT SUM(Salary) As SalaryTotal
 (    
     SELECT TOP 3 * FROM your_table ORDER BY ID
 )
```

If you want SUM of highest 3 salaries then you can ORDER BY Salary:

```
SELECT SUM(Salary) As SalaryTotal
(    
    SELECT TOP 3 * FROM your_table ORDER BY  salary DESC    
)
```